# Achartengine, how to stretch it beyond?

Tags: achartengine

I have many many X axis points so, chart seems too congested. Users can manually zoom or stretch the chart but is there a way to make chart extend beyond its parent view by default so my x axis values are not so congested?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visible range:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(min);
renderer.setXAxisMin(max);
```